# cordova project and Android 5.0

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to import a cordova project in Android Studio. I have seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936689/import-cordova-project-in-android-studio) but still have some issues which need clarification or a solution if exists. 
The cordova project is now imported in Android Studio and got an Gradle sync error. It suggests me to "install build tools 19.0.0 and sync project". I suppose that by doing this the cordova won't support Android 5. Am I right? Moreover, is there any workaround for that?

Comment: which cordova version are you using? the latest (3.7.0) should be compatible with android studio and android 5.0

Comment: @jcesarmobile 4.2.0 with "cordova -v" command but I think this refers to the CLI and 3.6.4 with the command "cordova platform version android" in the directory of the project. Moreover I just saw here http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide that "Cordova supports Android 2.3.x (Gingerbread, starting with Android API level 10) and 4.x. " . So is it compatible or not? I am quite confused now...

Comment: I think they have already released 3.7.0 for android, try with cordova platform add android@3.7.0 --usenpm

Comment: it seems that there is a bug on 3.7.0, they are going to release 3.7.1 soon