# cordova with android studio

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio

After creating the `Cordova` project successfully using the command line, I import the project `(projectname/platforms/android)` into Android Studio(1.1). However, I encounter `CordovaActivity` not found error in the `MainActivity` Java file.

How can I fix the issue to let the project recognise the `Cordova` library?
I have tried importing the Cordovalib as a module but it does not work. It says the lib is already included.

Comment: Have you build or run the cordova app first through CLI?

Comment: Maybe this link hleps you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936689/import-cordova-project-in-android-studio

Comment: Yup, I have done "cordova prepare android" & "cordova compile android". The app runs fine using command line "cordova run android" but It just doesn't work in Android Studio.