# Integrating Flutter On Existing Apps

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, flutter, dart

I just finished reading documentation on integrating Flutter functionality with existing apps here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app

I am unclear though and was wondering if anyone here knew if we can only integrate flutter functionality with existing native iOS/Android apps? Or if we can also integrate with ionic built apps as well?

Thank You:)

Comment: Related [add ionic framework to an existing android studio app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33068892/295004). As for instructions how, I don't know, as it feels like one author writing a single novel with three languages.

Comment: Thanks Morrison! Not exactly what I am trying to do though I want to add Flutter to an existing Ionic App not add an Ionic app to another app

Comment: If you read the answer I think its about loading the android project created by Ionic into Android Studio. So a possible path on the Android side. Given that both Ionic & Flutter are multi-platform solutions you are on your own if you want to "auto-magically" connect both without the native iOS/Android acting as a conduit.