# how to reload Genymotion after change files automatically in Android Studio

Tags: cordova, android-studio, genymotion

I am using Phonegap in Android Studio to build an app.
How to reload Genymotion after change files automatically? without press run app in Android Studio.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import Cordova project in Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936689/import-cordova-project-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Even when Android Studio 2.0 is released with the ["Instant Run" feature](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/11/android-studio-20-preview.html), it still requires you to hit Run to build and push to the device/emulator.