# how can i export android project from a cordova project

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have cordova project and it's without a folder for platforms , (android)

[image: screenshot from my project]

i want to export the android folder (src,res,assets,....) to import it to eclipse or android studio and export the apk file

Comment: When you get the message that says to add more detail, then do that. Don't add random text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import Cordova project in Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936689/import-cordova-project-in-android-studio)

Comment: Install `cordova` and run the following command line in the root of your Cordova project: `cordova build android`. If you haven't added Android as a platform, you'll need to run `cordova platform add android --save` first.
I would probably also swing by the official docs here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html